# Invoking the R help(...) command from a dos terminal

Tags: windows, r, dos

I want to invoke R-help from the dos terminal.  My attempts include:

```
R.exe -e "help(matrix)"
```

`Rscript.exe -e "help(matrix)"`

etc.

The results are all the same, explorer opens but does not find the file. The dos terminal shows no error, only:

```
> help('matrix')
starting httpd help server ... done
```

However, with Rgui, the help(matrix) commands works fine, which lends me to believe that the httpd help server is failing. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error on Windows 7 using R 2.12.1 Either of your commands works perfectly fine on my computer, and displays the help file in the browser (using Mozilla Firefox). Please add details : which R version, which Windows version, wich brouwser (I presume internet explorer), ...

Comment: @Joris I can reproduce it! Perhaps you could give your sessionInfo too!!

Comment: @David : Does explorer open with you but doesn't give the file, or does R just opens and closes (which would mean you have to set `options(help_type='html')` in your Rprofile.site file )

Comment: @Joris It's not explorer, it's Firefox, although that is irrelevant. R starts, processes the command specified by `-e` and then terminates. I don't have an Rprofile.site file, it's total vanilla R. `options(help_type)` is `html`. Do you know about the R httpd server and the fact that it only serves if the R process is running?

Comment: @Joris I don't mean `--vanilla`, I mean that R has been installed and no configurations changed.  The default for options("help_type") appears to be "html". I've just now installed R 2.12.2.

Comment: @David, well, I have R installed an no configurations changed. So we run the same one. With that difference that I can't reproduce and you can apparently.

Comment: @Joris Do you see the text "starting httpd help server ... done" on the R console the first time you run `help`?

Comment: @Joris I think you need to calm down a little. You seem to be heated. I do know you are knowledgeable. This is why it is hard to see why our understandings don't meet. I'm using `netstat -a | grep LISTENING` to detect when the R httpd server is running. It starts listening the first time you call `help()` and stops listening when the R process closes. The URL that I see is `http://127.0.0.1:17844/library/base/html/matrix.html` which matches the port shown by netstat. Perhaps the way your R opens the browser synchronously?

Comment: @Joris My computer is a modern 64 bit 8-core machine. I did try out `R --vanilla -e "options(help_type='html');help(matrix)"` before down-voting. I don't understand the need for the hostility. I think you would be better served by maintaining civility. Perhaps I am wrong. Perhaps you are wrong. Perhaps we are both right but haven't seen a misunderstanding. There's no need to insult me and no need to YELL.

Comment: @David : I cleaned up already. But I still fail to understand. Checked it on the i7 here : works. On the old one : works. I can't reproduce in any way. Apparently it keeps my R open a tiny bit of a fraction longer than yours, or my browser hits up faster?

Comment: @Joris It could very well be a timing thing, I agree.

Comment: @David : sorry for the heated discussion. Not my day today, I'm a bit touchy. Shouldn't have let it get the better of me though. -- this comment will self-destruct in some time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the R process that runs the httpd server terminates before it has a chance to serve up the content.

You'd need to find a way to keep the R process alive until it had served what you need, or run the R httpd server in service/daemon mode, if that is in fact possible.

For example, the following will keep the R process alive a little longer so that it can finish handling the http request:

```
R.exe -e "help(matrix); Sys.sleep(2)"
```

I can't find an abvious way to get the R httpd server running as a service/daemon, but I'm not really an expert. Perhaps someone else will know how to do it.

Comment: help works properly on a Linux command line, without needing any http facilities (unless it's using them behind the scenes without my realizing it).  So if that's true then there has to be a way to get R to do the same thing in a Windows command prompt.

Comment: @gsk3 OP is running Windows. As I already said, Windows runs its own httpd server to serve up help in the browser. I don't know how it works on Linux.

Comment: `help('matrix')` from command line works fine for me. Using Chrome as default browser.

Comment: @Sacha I repeat, does it work when the R process is not running? That is the problem that OP faces.

Comment: @Sacha : we're not talking here command line in R. We're talking DOS prompt (cmd) in Windows...

Comment: @Joris I can reproduce the OP's reported behaviour. Just because you can't doesn't mean that both OP and myself are imagining it.

Comment: @David : Please add specifications then : Which R version, which windows, which browser (that'll be internet explorer I assume),... I believe OP has a problem, I just don't agree it is the httpd server as I can issue both commands with perfect result.

Comment: @Joris `R.exe -e "help(matrix)"` results in the R process starting and then immediately terminating!  Do you have R configured to use static HTML or to generate it on demand?

Comment: Tried the solution R.exe -e "help(matrix); Sys.sleep(2)" and it worked. I am using R-2.12.1 and IE 7.0.6002. No to static help.